# Python MySQL Data string maipulation

Tags: python, mysql

This involves accessing data from a database, and maipulating the data in python. The database name is inb104, it contains two tables, car_details and cars_for_sale

Here's my code so far

```
def top_N_models(carbrand, num_of_highest):
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', \
                                     passwd='root', db='inb104')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = str("SELECT model, COUNT(model) AS Count FROM \
              cars_for_sale WHERE make='"+carbrand+"' GROUP BY \
              model ORDER BY count DESC, model LIMIT "+str(num_of_highest))
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    try:
            test = rows[0][0]
    except:
            print "No such make of car!"
    for row in rows:
            print str(row[0]), str(row[1])
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Now when this code is run through a series of test cases here are the results. on the failed test case it is expecting a return of nothing, instead of "No such make of car!"

```
Trying:
top_N_models('BMW', 6)
Expecting:
3 152
X5 72
5 39
1 19
7 9
M3 9
ok
Trying:
top_N_models('TOYOTA', 10)
Expecting:
COROLLA 275
LANDCRUISER 193
RAV4 189
HILUX 179
CAMRY 137
ECHO 69
KLUGER 61
YARIS 56
AURION 22
TARAGO 22
ok
Trying:
top_N_models('HOLDEN', 1)
Expecting:
COMMODORE 426
ok
Trying:
top_N_models('EDSEL', 10)
Expecting:
No such make of car!
ok
Trying:
top_N_models('TOYOTA', 0)
Expecting nothing
**********************************************************************
File "__main__", line 34, in __main__
Failed example:
top_N_models('TOYOTA', 0)
Expected nothing
Got:
No such make of car!
Trying:
top_N_models('MINI', 1)
Expecting:
COOPER 34
ok
Trying:
top_N_models('HSV', 10)
Expecting:
CLUBSPORT 21
COUPE 5
MALOO 5
AVALANCHE 2
GTS 2
GRANGE 1
ok
1 items had no tests:
__main__.top_N_models
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
1 of   7 in __main__
7 tests in 2 items.
6 passed and 1 failed.
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Comment: If someone (or yourself) solves your problem, mark the answer accepted and don't delete the question. If you solve it on your own, you are able to answer your own question after a certain delay.

Answer (score 1):

`rows` will be an empty list because your SQL statement has `LIMIT 0`.

Therefore, `rows[0]` returns an `IndexError`, triggering the `except`.

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you're suggesting here.

Comment: The question is about why the failed test case returns `no such make of car`, correct? Trace your code for the case `top_N_models('TOYOTA', 0)`. You will find that the SQL statement contains `LIMIT 0`, meaning that it returns zero records.

Comment: Ahh ok, yes this was the question, but i'm fairly new to Python and have been unable to fix this problem.

Comment: `rows[0]` tries to retrieve the first element of the list `rows`. But `rows` is empty. That raises an error. When an error is raised inside the `try` block, execution moves onto the `except` block.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but the except has to print the "No such make of car" in order to pass a test case. Then another test case is given where it is blank, so instead of returning the except, it must return nothing

Comment: Oh sorry. It wasn't totally clear from the question what the problem exactly is -- it only references the "failed test case". I'd say you need another SQL statement to check `count(make)`. Being that I don't know the details of this assignment, I'll leave the rest to you.